# what is another logic which has time execution faster than randperm

Tags: matlab, random

I am new matlab user.
Now, I'am doing my work by using matlab software. but I have problem to improve my code in order to have fast time execution.
right now, I have to make a matrix(A,10,C)) which has the value integer [ 1 10].
currently, I am using logic `randperm`. here my code :

```
for c=1:C,
   for a=1:A,
       result(a,:,c)=randperm(10);
   end
end
```

but when I tried to analyze with profile viewer. That code take a more time.

so I wish that there is someone want to share his/her experience about this.
thanks you.
regard

Comment: Have you tried pre-allocating your matrix (define `result = zeros(A,10,C)` before the for-loops)? That could be the real reason behind the performance drop.

Comment: yes, I have tried to use pre-allocating size in my matrix. @Jacob

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks your for your welcoming. I will read FAQ as soon as possible.

Comment: The practice of having variables with names which differ only in case (*eg* `c` and `C`) will result in ruin and despair.

Comment: If, as @Jacob's answer suggests, your code takes `0.0016s` to execute its performance is not something you should be worrying about at an early stage in your Matlab development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution but it does not have the nice properties of `randperm` regarding the distribution of your random numbers:

```
[~,result_alt] = sort( rand(A,10,C) , 2);
```

A quick profile shows that your method takes approximately 1.6e-3 seconds on average when `A = C = 10` whereas this method takes 5.6e-5 seconds on average.

#### Note:

Older version of MATLAB won't support the `~` operator. If so, try:

```
[vals result_alt] = sort( rand(A,10,C) , 2);
```

and ignore `vals`.

Comment: I'm assuming you want a matrix where each row has numbers from 1-10  in random positions?

Comment: @engineering2008: Then how is the `result_alt` not like your solution? Apart from the distribution as I mentioned.

Comment: I don't know why I cannot run your code in My matlab. I am using Matlab old version R2009a. @Jacob

Comment: OK, you need to say that you cannot run my code. From your first comment, it seemed like it ran and gave a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

This must be fast.

```
result = ceil(10 * rand(A, 10, C));
```

Comment: Fast but wrong, I fear. OP does not want 10 random numbers between 1 and 10  in the matrix, but rather a random permutation of the elements in [1:10].